# Limit comparison test rules

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]Why is it that I cannot use the limit comparison test for the series from n=4 to infinity of (n^2)/(n^3-3)? When I use the direct comparison test it works, but for the limit comparison test it does not work. When I do the direct comparison test, I get the Series diverges, however when I do the limit comparison test, the series converges at 1. Are these results correct or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it does not work?

Comment: Can you be more specific: what works and what not?

Comment: @zkutch I just edited the question, does it help?

Comment: Please show your work on using both methods. Else we cannot answer your question unless we can rule out possible errors in your work.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Direct comparison I understand as simple inequality, but what you mean under "limit comparison test"? If asymptotic one, then it also give divergence.

Comment: @amWhy sorry about that I'm new to this. Is this better?

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewLu!

Comment: Yes, now it's better. The most best will be if/when you find time and type formulas in place of image in question. Now we can see, that N. S. guess is correct: you made limit comparison correct, but do not interpret it correctly - limit equal one gives divergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely using the limit comparison test wrong.

Note here that
$$
\lim_n \frac{\frac{n^2}{n^3-3}}{\frac{1}{n}}=1
$$
Therefore, as $\sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, your series diverges.

Comment: @amWhy just added work

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I reread some notes on the limit comparison test and realized that if the limit results in something finite and positive, it does not mean it converges, it just means that both either converge or diverge.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what is wrong with the answer?